# Rationalizing Denominator question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I feel totally stupid asking this considering I am in precalc but our professor threw this question at us. I have the answer, but he didn't provide the process:

Rationalize the denominator:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[7]{x^4}}$$

The answer is:

$$\frac{\sqrt[7]{x^3}}{x}$$

Please explain it how he got there. I know you have to multiply by

$$\frac{\sqrt[7]{x^4}}{\sqrt[7]{x^4}}$$

But I end up with:
$$\frac{\sqrt[7]{x^4}}{x^4}$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you write it as: $\dfrac{x^{3/7}}{x^1} = \dfrac{x^{3/7}}{x^{7/7}}$? Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to multiply it by $\frac {\sqrt [7]{x^3}}{\sqrt [7]{x^3}}$  The numerator in the answer shows that.  Then ${\sqrt [7]{x^3}}\cdot {\sqrt [7]{x^4}}={\sqrt [7]{x^7}}=1$.  I find it easier to use fractional exponents, changing ${\sqrt [7]{x^4}}$ to $x^{\frac 47}$ and proceeding.  You could do that and see if it helps.

Comment: It's coming back to me now. I need to fill in the fraction basically.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is that you're following a rule that says you should multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt[7]{x}$.

One the bottom you've got
$$
\sqrt[7]{x}\cdot\sqrt[7]{x}\cdot\sqrt[7]{x}\cdot\sqrt[7]{x}.
$$
What you need on the bottom to get rid of the radical is
$$
\sqrt[7]{x}\cdot\sqrt[7]{x}\cdot\sqrt[7]{x}\cdot\sqrt[7]{x}\cdot\sqrt[7]{x}\cdot\sqrt[7]{x}\cdot\sqrt[7]{x}.
$$
Multiply that out an you just have $x$, with no radical.

So you have to multiply both the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt[7]{x}^3$.